# Using structure matlab code

Tags: matlab, structure

I have recently been working in Matlab, so there are questions. Look at the code, please. If amountOfOptions = 2, I should get OptionPrice = [x x] . Vector Size OptionPrice(1x2). It seems he receives the output it produces but it gives the last result of the assignment.

```
function [startStockPrice, strike, barrier, riskFreeRate, timeToExpiry, volatility, CallOrPut, UpOrDown, OptionPrice, time] = OutBarrierOption(amountOfOptions)
    %%%%%%%%%% Option parameters %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    startStockPrice   = 70 + 40 * rand(1,amountOfOptions);      % Stock price starts at $100.
    strike = 120 + 30 * rand(1,amountOfOptions);                 % Strike price for the option ($).
    barrier = 300 + 300 * rand(1,amountOfOptions);              % Barrier price for the option ($).
    riskFreeRate = 0.05 + 0.1 * rand(1,amountOfOptions);        % 0.5 annual percent.
    timeToExpiry = fix(1 + 3 * rand(1, amountOfOptions));       % Lifetime of the option in years. (Time to maturity)
    volatility   = 0.35 + 0.3 * rand(1,amountOfOptions);        % 20% annual volatility.                                          % UpOrDown - 'U' or 'D'
    M = 1e4; % Number of Monte-Carlo trials
    N = 100; % Number of observations
    OptionPrice = 0;
    tic;
    for k = 1:amountOfOptions
        dt(k)=timeToExpiry(k)/N;
        for i=1:M
            S(1) = startStockPrice(k)*exp((riskFreeRate(k)-(volatility(k)*volatility(k)/2)*dt(k)) + volatility(k)*sqrt(dt(k))*randn);
            final_vals=[S(1)];
            for j=1:N-1;
                S(j + 1) = S(j)* exp((riskFreeRate(k) - 0.5* volatility(k)*volatility(k))*dt(k) + volatility(k)* sqrt(dt(k))* randn);
                final_vals=S(1:j+1);
            end
        end
        if max(final_vals) <= barrier(k)
            option_values=max(final_vals - strike(k),0); % Evaluate the Call option options
            present_vals = exp(-riskFreeRate(k)*timeToExpiry(k))*option_values; % Discount under r-n assumption
            OptionPrice = mean(present_vals); % Take the average
        else
            % Hit the barrier, so the option is withdrawn.
            present_vals = 0;
            OptionPrice = mean(present_vals);
        end

    end
    time = toc;
    end
```

Comment: Try OptionPrice(k)? OptionPrice seems to be a scalar and not a vector the way you coded it. Also, this is very difficult to read... Can you reduce the example to a minimal working one? Also, CTRL+A plus CTRL+I aids readability

Comment: Maybe you could make your post clearer by posting what you expect and what you got instead..

Comment: I want to receive the output vector values of OptionPrice. In that short code it is turned, when i replaced OptionPrice=[] instead OptionPrice = 0 and OptionPrice change on OptionPrice(k). But if I do the same thing in a large code, then the output is OptionPrice = []

Comment: It worked, but I did not understand why he did not want to initially display the correct value

Comment: What worked, the (k)? Because you didn't save the values in a vector but as a single value. If you run it n times the one value gets overwritten every time and you only get the value from the last iteration. In your case n=2